# Receiving data over UDP and send by TCP

Tags: networking, tcp, proxy, udp

My networking isn't very good but trying to figure this out.

Is it possible to receive data through UDP and then sending it on to another server via TCP?

So would be like
UDP Client -> *(Recieve UDP Datagram)* Proxy *(Send TCP Packet)* -> TCP Server

Comment: And what problems do you see in uniting both UDP and TCP clients in one place (proxy)?

Comment: It's taking data in via udp and the proxy is acting like a udp server there and then sending the same data to another server over tcp. I'm just not sure this is possible currently I'm seeing very different data levels in and out. So 100 messages in udp and less out over tcp but if I use tcp in and tcp out see 100 messages.

Sorry if this is something simple not really good at networking stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problems in acting like the UDP server and the TCP client simultaneously.

At first, we need to establish connection with the TCP Server (as you don't need UDP datagrams if you have nowhere to redirect it, I guess).

```
SOCKET tcp_socket = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
sockaddr_in tcp_address; // this is the address of 'TCP Server'
tcp_address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(tcp_server_ip);
tcp_address.sin_port = htons(tcp_server_port);
tcp_address.sin_family = PF_INET;
connect(tcp_socket, (SOCKADDR*)&tcp_address, sizeof(tcp_address));
```

After the tcp_socket is connected, we can create UDP socket:

```
SOCKET udp_socket = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
sockaddr_in udp_local_address; // this is your local address for receiving datagrams
udp_local_address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(udp_proxy_ip);
udp_local_address.sin_port = htons(udp_proxy_port);
udp_local_address.sin_family = PF_INET;

if(bind(udp_socket, (SOCKADDR*)&udp_local_address, sizeof(udp_local_address)) == SOCKET_ERROR))
{
  // WSAGetLastError()
  return false;
}
```

So, now you need just receive datagrams from the UDP socket and send it to the TCP socket:

```
sockaddr_in udp_remote_address; // this is the adrees of 'UDP Client'
udp_remote_address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(udp_client_ip);
udp_remote_address.sin_port = htons(udp_client_port);
udp_remote_address.sin_family = PF_INET;

char buffer[9016];
const int read_size = recvfrom(udp_socket, buffer, 9016, 0, (SOCKADDR*)&udp_remote_address, sizeof(udp_remote_address));
if(read_size > 0)
{
  if(send(tcp_socket, buffer, read_size, NULL) == SOCKET_ERROR)
  {
    // WSAGetLastError();
  }
}
```

To check whether the tcp_socket is connected, you can use that code (it checks whether the socket is writable):

```
const timeval tv = { 0, 0 };
fd_set fd;
FD_ZERO(&fd);
FD_SET(tcp_socket, &fd);
select(NULL, NULL, &fd, NULL, &tv);
if(FD_ISSET(tcp_socket, &fd))
{
}
```

Comment: TCP doesn't have clients or servers; it is a peer-to-peer protocol. The client/server concept is an application-layer concept.